# Table rollover hightlight change text colour

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a php populated table, which has alternate row colors and works fine, what i am now trying to do is change the colour of the text in the table row when it is highlighted.

The code below shows the table highlight, which works fine but i can not get the color element to change.

```
 <tr class="active"  bgcolor="#363636" onMouseOver="this.bgColor='gold';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#363636';" onMouseOver="this.color='#fff';">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two, conflicting `onMouseOver` attributes. Instead of doing this, why not use the `:hover` pseudoclass?

```
tr {
    background-color: #363636;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: gold;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

If you really want to use `onMouseOver`, you can do this:

```
oneMouseOver="this.bgColor='gold'; this.color='#ffffff';";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css:

```
tr:hover {
    color: White;
}
```

All of your items can be redone with CSS

```
tr {
  background-color: #363636;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: Gold;
  color: White;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.style.color` instead of `this.color`, and you can set it all in the same attribute:

```
onMouseOver="this.bgColor='gold'; this.style.color='#fff';"
```

By the way try to avoid inline javascript like that, so you have a separation between html/css and your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending if you have multiple columns in each row you can update the style of the text in a few different ways. I tested both of these in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaCjP/) and they both work.

If you only want the color updated when a particular cell is moused over:

```
 <tr class="active"  bgcolor="#363636" onMouseOver="this.bgColor='gold';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#363636';" >
      <td onMouseOver="this.style.color='#fff';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#000';">
        hey
      </td>
    </tr>
```

and if you want the color updated when any cell in the row is moused over:

```
<tr class="active"  bgcolor="#363636" 
   onMouseOver="this.bgColor='gold';this.style.color='#fff';" 
   onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#363636';this.style.color='#000';">
```

Comment: hi thans that actually only changes the color of the column if i hover over that column and not the row.

Comment: @user1691024 yes, that is why I provided two different examples depending on what you needed. The bottom example should work when the row is moused over, and not just one cell.

Comment: @user1691024 here is the JSfiddle for the bottom example http://jsfiddle.net/xaCjP/2/